# java: standard interface with getName() method?

Tags: java, interface

Is there a standard Java interface with a `getName()` method that returns a string? I keep finding I have to make my own:

```
/** objects which know their own names, 
 *  e.g. that are indexed in a Map by their name
 */
interface NamedObject
{
   public String getName()
}
```

but I'd much rather use a standard one if it's out there.

---

edit for an example -- which I think is somewhat of a red herring to my question, so I specifically do **not** want answers suggesting alternatives that are specific to the following situation. (I've run into the need for a `NamedObject` interface several times, so I was hoping it was something in a standard library.)

But since you asked for some background context, here it is:

```
@Override public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    Object obj = e.getSource();             
    if (obj instanceof NamedObject)
    {
        String name = ((NamedObject)obj).getName();
        /* do something based on object's name */
    }
}
```

In my current project, I have a system with three elements: a source, a transmission method, and a receiver. I want to get some information from the source to a receiver, and I control the implementation of both. The transmission method unfortunately is stuck using an object that supports ChangeListener, so all the receiver gets a `ChangeEvent` with which I can get a source object.

So I have to use implied shared semantics between my source and receiver, i.e. there's a shared understanding that the source object passed in the ChangeEvent is of class X, where I can pick class X. In this case, all I really care about is the name, from which I can get additional data. I can define my own interface, I was just hoping to be able to use a standard interface since the source and receiver are in different .jar files...

Comment: As far as I know, not in the Java SE API.

Comment: How exactly do you want to use this method? Show some examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, not in the Java SE API.

It is debatable whether a generic `NamedObject` interface makes sense. Consider for example a `Person` class and a `UnixNamedPipe` class. Both could share the same `NamedObject` interface, but their names actually have vastly different semantics. I can't see for example a case where it would make sense to have a `Collection<NamedObject>` with both `Person`s and `UnixNamedPipe`s.

It would make sense to define such an interface if you have `PetCat`, `PetDog` and maybe `PetRock` classes. But then you will probably have a `Pet` super class that already defines `getName()` for all pets. In this case, what the concept of what a "name" is will not change from one pet to another.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like that java API provides.As you are doing,go with it and implement your own class with this interface.

Answer (score -1):

All objects in java are inherited from the Object.class.
There is a **toString()** method which is often used to get a representive name of the object.

You can re-implement this method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {      
    return "The name of this Object";
}
```

Comment: "public String toString(): Returns a string representation of the object." It's not designed to give the class's name, and it's also not the default behaviour.

Comment: I think he wants the name of the object, not the name of the class. He called his Interface "NamedObject"

Comment: Then it still makes no sense to use toString() for that, it's not its default nor its expected behaviour; also it's available in every class but he can't check if it's implemented with that semantic in mind in a specific object.